# How to correctly check the size passed to malloc() calloc() realloc() as well as their return value?

Tags: c, pointers, size, return-value, allocation

If I have understood correctly, it is also important to check that the desired space passed to malloc(), calloc() or realloc() does not exceed the SIZE_MAX constant after the multiplication with the sizeof(desired_type). In order to make sure that does not happen I started to do something like this in my codes:

```
#define MAX_CHAIN (50)


#ifndef SIZE_MAX
#define SIZE_MAX (~(size_t)0)
#endif

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

    char **parsed_string;

    if(MAX_CHAIN > SIZE_MAX/sizeof(char*) || 
    (parsed_string=(char**)malloc(MAX_CHAIN * sizeof(char*)))==NULL){
        printf("%s\n", "Error, cannot allocate memory");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*Otherwise pointer is valid and the execution continues*/


}
```

So it basically checks for two things:

1. That the requested memory is not bigger that SIZE_MAX
2. That the pointer returned by malloc() is valid.

My questions are: Is it a correct to do these checks? Is this considered as good practice or should I use something else instead? Also, can someone explain why the allocation is limited by SIZE_MAX?

Comment: To all answerers, an example scenario: Imagine you try to allocate `((size_t) -1) / 2` integers, which are 4 bytes each. Multiplying those two numbers together will overflow and cause malloc() to allocate less memory than you thought. malloc() might "succeed" because it receives a smaller size than you intended. That's what this question is about.

Comment: That's what I thought! Thank you for this comment. I wish someone could formulate a complete answer.

Comment: Good point. However, [please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: I use a C++ compiler, that's why I need to cast here. I would not do it otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct to do the checks, some would say pedantic.  Some thoughts

```
#include <stdint.h>
...
// MAX_CHAIN > SIZE_MAX/sizeof(char*)
MAX_CHAIN > (SIZE_MAX - sizeof(char*) +1)/sizeof(char*)
// This deals with SIZE_MAX/sizeof(char*) rounding toward 0
```

A return value of NULL is valid if memory allocation size is 0.

Watch for attempted negative memory allocation requests as many requests are formed with `int` (signed) even though the request takes `size_t` (unsigned).

---

Memory allocation is limited to `SIZE_MAX` as in typical systems cannot allocate `(size_t)-1` or any where new that.  Look at the C standard definition of `RSZIE_MAX` which is closely related to your concerns.

C11dr §K.3.4 3
Extremely large object sizes are frequently a sign that an object’s size was calculated incorrectly. For example, negative numbers appear as very large positive numbers when converted to an unsigned type like size_t. Also, some implementations do not support objects as large as the maximum value that can be represented by type size_t.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, one last thing: How would you take care of the negative allocation (like in the example you give)? What do you mean by not "getting the answer one expect"? `MAX_CHAIN` could be interpreted as a negative value?

Comment: @aeqr as given `MAX_CHAIN (50)` is a signed integer with a value of `50`.  Your usage of it does not appear to be a problem.  But since it is a signed integer, it may infect `signed-ness` into various other calculations that you think are being done unsigned.  It would have been safer to use `MAX_CHAIN ((size_t)50)`.  It is this subtle effect that messes integer calculation at the extreme integer range.  That is where your code is trying to operate, at the extreme ends.  Note: integer math via the pre-processor works with, I think, with intmax_t and uintmax_t.  Walk carefully at the fringe.

Comment: @aeqr To "take care of the negative allocation" consider `RSIZE_MAX`.  I think it is just what you want.  C11 K,3,4 "recommended that RSIZE_MAX be defined as the smaller of the size of the largest object supported or (SIZE_MAX >> 1)", 1), even if this limit is smaller than the size of
some legitimate, but very large, objects. Implementations targeting machines with small address spaces may wish to define RSIZE_MAX as SIZE_MAX, which means that there is no object size that is considered a runtime-constraint violation.

Comment: Just to be completely clear about it, is this correct?:                                                                        `#ifndef SIZE_MAX
#define SIZE_MAX (~(size_t)0)
#endif
#ifndef RSIZE_MAX
#define RSIZE_MAX (SIZE_MAX >> 1)
#endif`

Comment: And then of course I would use `RSIZE_MAX` in the allocation, instead of `SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: @aeqr Looks good except _maybe_ `(SIZE_MAX >> 1)` does a type conversion?  Hmm maybe `(SIZE_MAX >> 1u)`?  Always a bit fuzzy about shifts and the effect of the type of that pesky `1`.  Be sure to #include <stdint.h> first, as you are able.

Comment: @aeqr Parting comment:  Having a central function that calls `malloc()` and checks the size is a good idea.  But I'd even campaign to limit `malloc()` to even a fraction of `RSIZE_MAX`  (e.g. RSIZE_MAX/2).  There are just so many potential potholes with code and arrays near the limits of the system, I'd like to have a throttle on that beast by a good margin.  This tighter limit may be practical in a program, but not in a supporting library.  TTFN

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42670/discussion-between-chux-and-aeqr)

Answer (score -1):

To check that the result is ok just see if it's equal to NULL

Comment: That doesn't tell you if the the amount of memory you requested overflowed.

Comment: It sort of does, I would say that the requested data may fail for a number of reasons, but as you have written in your code you check for NULL already, the realloc could fail because of mem fragmentation etc. It's implementation specific. Microsoft give a whole load of debugging tools that allow you to walk the heap etc

Comment: I Guess I don't know what you mean by overflowed?

Comment: @Angus Connell With 32-bit math, 4-byte pointers and `MAX_CHAIN =0x4000_0001`, then `MAX_CHAIN * sizeof(char*)` is 0x0000_0004 (overflow).  A `malloc(4)` will nicely allocate, but not provide the 0x1_0000_0004 bytes needed.